# Selecting values based on threshold using Python

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

The present code selects minimum values by scanning the adjoining elements in the same and the succeeding row. However, I want the code to select all the values if they are less than the threshold value. For example, in row 2, I want the code to pick both 0.86 and 0.88 since both are less than 0.9, and not merely minimum amongst 0.86,0.88. Basically, the code should pick up the minimum value if all the adjoining elements are greater than the threshold. If that's not the case, it should pick all the values less than the threshold.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

Pe = np.random.rand(5,5)

def minValues(arr):
    n, m = arr.shape
    assert n >= 1 and m >= 2
    res = []
    i, j = 0, np.argmin(arr[0,:])
    res.append((i, j))
    iPrev = jPrev = -1
    while iPrev < n-1:
        cases = [(i, j-1), (i, j+1), (i+1, j)]
        minVal = np.inf
        iMin = jMin = -1
        # Find the best candidate (smallest value)
        for (i2, j2) in cases:
            if i2 == iPrev and j2 == jPrev: # No cycles
                continue
            if i2 < 0 or i2 >= n or j2 < 0 or j2 >= m: # No out-of-bounds
                continue
            if arr[i2, j2] < minVal:
                iMin, jMin = i2, j2
                minVal = arr[i2, j2]
        assert not np.isinf(minVal)
        # Store it and update the values
        res.append((iMin, jMin))
        iPrev, jPrev = i, j
        i, j = iMin, jMin
    return np.array(res)

T=minValues(Pe)
Path=Pe[T.T[0], T.T[1]]
```

Current output:[image]

Desired output: [image]

Comment: @Wiz123 after you pick both 0.86 and 0.88 since both are less than 0.9, do you want to scan the adjoining elements in the same and the succeeding row for 0.86 and 0.88 separately, or only for the minimum of these, that is, only scan for 0.86? Also, your code does not stop scanning when it reaches the bottom row, but rather one step after reaching the bottom row; is this what you intend? More specifically, when do you want the scan to stop?

Comment: @constantstranger For values less than the threshold, I want to scan the adjoining elements of minimum of both the values i.e. 0.86. The code should stop the scan when it has reached the bottom row and move forward only for values less than the threshold.

Comment: Got it. In that case, the answer by @Ander Gurtubay looks like it does what you need.

Comment: I don't think so. The outputs are different than what I expected them to be.

Comment: I don't understand your desired output. You say, you "... want the code to select all the values if they are less than the threshold value", however, your desired output does not show either of elements [0,0] or [0,3] being selected, although they are less than 0.9. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def minValues(arr):
  n, m = arr.shape
  assert n >= 1 and m >= 2
  res = []
  i, j = 0, np.argmin(arr[0,:])
  print(f"Values i, j are: {i}, {j}")
  res.append((i, j))
  iPrev = jPrev = -1
  while iPrev < n-1:
      lowerVals = []
      print(f"Values iPrev, jPrev are: {iPrev}, {jPrev}")
      cases = [(i, j-1), (i, j+1), (i+1, j)]
      print(f"Posible cases are: {cases}")
      minVal = np.inf
      print(f"MinVal is: {minVal}")
      iMin = jMin = -1
      # Find the best candidate (smallest value)
      for (i2, j2) in cases:
          if i2 == iPrev and j2 == jPrev: # No cycles
              continue
          if i2 < 0 or i2 >= n or j2 < 0 or j2 >= m: # No out-of-bounds
              continue
          if arr[i2, j2] < arr[i, j]:
              lowerVals.append((i2, j2))
          if arr[i2, j2] < minVal:
              iMin, jMin = i2, j2
              minVal = arr[i2, j2]
      if not lowerVals: lowerVals.append((iMin, jMin))
      print(f"Values iMin, jMin are: {iMin}, {jMin}")    
      print(f"MinVal is: {minVal}")
      print(f"Lower values are: {lowerVals}")
      assert not np.isinf(minVal)
      # Store it and update the values
      res += lowerVals
      print(f"Final res after current iteration: {res}\n")
      iPrev, jPrev = i, j
      i, j = iMin, jMin
  return np.array(res)
```

I used the prints for debugging, but I just check in each iteration all the values which are lower than the current value and add them to path at the end of the iteration.

Edit: introducing the extra line of my comment you get the above code, this should work.

Comment: With this code, the output is ```Path =array([0.19933102, 0.88295961, 0.85583994, 0.24968684, 0.0054003,0.65107604])```. However, it should be  ```Path=array([0.19933102, 0.43818404, 0.76010604, 0.90453548, 0.85583994, 0.24968684, 0.0054003 , 0.65661159, 0.65107604])```

Comment: Sorry, my code does not work when none of the values is lower than the one of the iteration, to solve this just insert this line of code after the loop: `if not lowerVals: lowerVals.append((iMin, jMin))`, this generates the following output for me: `Path=array([0.2   , 0.44  , 0.76  , 0.9   , 0.88  , 0.86  , 0.25  , 0.0054, 0.66  , 0.65  ])`

Comment: How will the code change if I want to select both the values less than the threshold (not just min amongst the two) and select no value above the threshold?

Comment: How do I modify the code if I need to select all the values less than the threshold, not just the minimum amongst all?

Comment: This is exactly what it does, after the for loop the list `lowerVals` contains the points with lower values than the threshold, but you still need the minimum value of the neighbours in case none of the values is lower than the threshold. After the loop we check if `lowerVals` list is empty and if it is, we add the minimum values to it, after this the `res` final list gets updated appending the `lowerVals` values.

Comment: Right...but when it selects all the values less than threshold, it picks the minimum amongst these. Instead, I want it to select all the values and follow the entire algorithm. Basically, it would branch out into multiple paths, starting with each value less than the threshold. Is there a way I can share what I am seeking? I can explain better using a heatmap but I am not able to upload here.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem - looking at hydrology flow/downhill direction?

The issue with the description is that you don't specify *which* of the neighboring cells to iterate to next, meaning, if you have three neighboring cells that are lower, they all get added to the output array but which is selected?  Also, when looking back through the output array how do you know which ones got added with respect to a single neighboring cell?  I went about this by selecting the lowest value of the neighboring cells with less than the source cell's value (biggest dropoff), then continued the search from that cell and so on.  For each iteration, there is a new nested list of the cell positions for the neighboring cells that are lower.  This could readily be updated any number of ways, to include exporting an additional list showing which cells were used for search (essentially the path taken, while there might be highlighted cells (lower) that were not visited per se.

```
import numpy as np

Pe = np.random.rand(5,5)

def nearestMin(arr, output_arr=[[0,0]], n=0, m=0):
    if m==arr.shape[1]:
        return output_arr
    lower_vals = np.argwhere(arr < arr[n,m])
    if lower_vals.size == 0:  #No values anywhere less than current cell
        return output_arr
    #Get offset from current point, as tuple of x and y distance
    smaller_adjacents = np.where(Pe < Pe[n, m])
    if smaller_adjacents[0].size == 0:  #No lower points anywhere
        return output_arr 
    ind = np.where((abs(n - smaller_adjacents[0]) <= 1 ) & \
        (abs(m - smaller_adjacents[1]) <= 1))[0] 
    if ind.size == 0:  #No lower points neighboring
        return output_arr
    xs, ys = smaller_adjacents[0][ind], smaller_adjacents[1][ind]
    lower_neighbors = np.vstack((xs, ys)).T.tolist()
    output_arr.append(lower_neighbors) #Unbracket to have final output array be flat (2d)
    n_depth = [Pe[x,y] for x,y in lower_neighbors] - Pe[n,m]
    biggest_drop = np.where(n_depth==n_depth.min())[0][0]
    lowest_neighbor = lower_neighbors[biggest_drop]
    return nearestMin(arr, output_arr, n=lowest_neighbor[0], m=lowest_neighbor[1])

nearestMin(Pe)
```

If you want the path, the same code can be modified as shown below to return that as a second array.  In this example, the values for the path are listed.  Each value corresponds to the "list of lists" item in the first returned array of neighboring lower values.  Again, not sure exactly what you're going for.

```
import numpy as np

Pe = np.random.rand(5,5)

def nearestMin(arr, output_arr=[[0,0]], path=[], n=0, m=0):
    #Initialize path variable properly
    if output_arr == [[0,0]]:
        path.append(arr[0,0])
    if m==arr.shape[1]:
        return (output_arr, path)
    lower_vals = np.argwhere(arr < arr[n,m])
    if lower_vals.size == 0:  #No values anywhere less than current cell
        return (output_arr, path)
    #Get offset from current point, as tuple of x and y distance
    smaller_adjacents = np.where(Pe < Pe[n, m])
    if smaller_adjacents[0].size == 0:  #No lower points anywhere
        return (output_arr, path)
    ind = np.where((abs(n - smaller_adjacents[0]) <= 1 ) & \
        (abs(m - smaller_adjacents[1]) <= 1))[0] 
    if ind.size == 0:  #No lower points neighboring
        return (output_arr, path)
    xs, ys = smaller_adjacents[0][ind], smaller_adjacents[1][ind]
    lower_neighbors = np.vstack((xs, ys)).T.tolist()
    output_arr.append(lower_neighbors) #Unbracket to have final output array be flat (2d)
    n_depth = [Pe[x,y] for x,y in lower_neighbors] - Pe[n,m]
    biggest_drop = np.where(n_depth==n_depth.min())[0][0]
    lowest_neighbor = lower_neighbors[biggest_drop]
    path.append(arr[lowest_neighbor[0], lowest_neighbor[1]])
    return nearestMin(arr, output_arr, path, n=lowest_neighbor[0], m=lowest_neighbor[1])
    

nearestMin(Pe)
```

Comment: How do I generate the path? For a random 5x5 matrix, I get the following: ```[[0, 0], [[0, 1], [1, 1]], [[0, 2]], [[1, 3]]]```. I need to be able to plot the path on a heatmap.

Comment: Check the updated solution, in the second part